# How to make Visual Source Safe ignore certain directories?

Tags: vss, ignore

Even when you drop the parent directory into VSS,it should also ignore the specified directories.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can [exclude files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173809.aspx), but not directories to my knowledge.